How to Simplify This Limit of a Summation
I've been attempting to simplify an equation for a few weeks now. I've managed to get it down to this:
$$\displaystyle S=r^2\cdot\lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\left(\displaystyle\dfrac{1}{n}\sin{\left( \dfrac{\pi}{n} \right)} \cdot\sum_{i=1}^{n}\left(\sqrt{ \left(\cos^2{\left( \dfrac{\pi}{n}\right)} \right)\cdot\displaystyle\left(2i-1\right)^{2}+\left(\sqrt{n^2-(i-1)^2}+\sqrt{n^2-i^2} \right)^2}\right)\right)$$
I tried converting it into an integral, but it didn't seem to work out the way I tried.
Using this formula:
$$
\displaystyle \int^{b}_{a}(\displaystyle f(x))dx = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty }\left(\displaystyle \sum^{n}_{i=1}\left(\displaystyle f\left(\displaystyle x_{i}\right)\cdot\Delta x\right)\right) \\
\Delta x = \dfrac{a-b}{n} \\
x_{i} = a+i\Delta x
$$
I assumed $a=0$ and $b=1$:
$$
\displaystyle f(x_{i}) = \sqrt{ \left(\cos^2{\left( \dfrac{\pi}{n}\right)} \right)\cdot\displaystyle\left(2i-1\right)^{2}+\left(\sqrt{n^2-(i-1)^2}+\sqrt{n^2-i^2} \right)^2}\cdot\sin{\left( \dfrac{\pi}{n} \right)}\Rightarrow \\
\displaystyle f(x_{i}) = \sqrt{ \left(\cos^2{\left( \dfrac{\pi}{n}\right)} \right)\cdot\displaystyle\left(2nx_{i}-1\right)^{2}+\left(\sqrt{n^2-\left( nx_{i}-1 \right)^2}+\sqrt{n^2-\left(nx_{i} \right)^2} \right)^2}\cdot\sin{\left( \dfrac{\pi}{n} \right)}
$$
I got stuck with left over $n$'s.
I know this should equal $2\pi r^2$, but I don't know how to simplify a summation like this.


For anyone interested:
Explanation of where this equations is from:

 I wanted to solve for the surface area of a sphere using only polygons. This equations models the surface of a hemisphere using only trapezoids. (here's a 3D rendering desmos graph of the shape)


Taking the limit $n\to\infty$
$$S=\pi r^2\int_0^1\sqrt{4x^2+(\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1+x^2})^2}dx$$
$$=\frac{\pi r^2}{\sqrt2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{\frac{\cos t+2\sin t+1}{\sin t}}\cos t ,dt=\sqrt2\pi r^2\int_0^1\sqrt{\frac{2t+1}t}\frac{1-t^2}{(1+t^2)^2}dt=2.2462003...$$

@Svyatoslav. Very interesting integral using $\sqrt{\frac{2 t+1}{t}}=u$ and partial fraction decomposition.

Thanks for the answer.
Plugging in the first expression you had cor $S$, it evaluated to the wrong value. It works out if:
$$
S = \pi r^2 \displaystyle \int^{1}_{0}\displaystyle \sqrt{4x^2+\left(\sqrt{1-x^2}+\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)^2}dx
$$
I'm working through evaluating from there.
Thanks for the help.
